# 3 Way smart dimmer switch install with switched Load wire in junction box 1 and live wire at junction box 2

Tags: switch, dimmer-switch, smart-switch

I want to install wifi 3-way smart dimmer switches for a chandelier and in junction box 1 it looks like they ran the power to the light and back down to Junction box 1 with 14/2 Romex.  Then they ran 14/3 Romex between the 2 switch junction boxes.

The original 3 way switch in switch box 1 was wired as follows: they have the red and white wires of 14/3 as travelers and then the load wire from the light into the 3 way switch. (the black wire of the 14/3 is tied to power (live).

In switch box 2 all they have is the 14/3 Romex with the red/white traveler wires and the black wire that is connected directly to the power.

How can I install 3 way smart dimmer switches with this configuration?

[image]

Additional Information:
In the main downstairs switch box they have about 7 incoming Romex cables I've been able to identify where 4 of them are going. From what I've read it appears that a 14/2 cable was tied into the power and ran directly to the chandelier then they ran a 14/2 cable back down to the switch box (far right side of picture) the black wire of this cable was ran to the 3 way switch and when the power is on there is no voltage to this black wire. The black wire for the 14/3 cable was tied to the hot wires and white/red wires are connected to switch w/ black wire with no voltage described above.

Here is a link to the wifi switch I'm trying to install that may help to explain my wiring dilemma.

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A1mMVtqHNuS.pdf

Comment: With the wiring you described you will not be installing a smart switch that needs neutral.  End of subject. However, there appears to be a lot more going on inside the pictured junction box. We need the rest of the story on all that, and then maybe we can figure something out.

Comment: Actually, it *may* be possible to flip things around so that you can install a smart switch in this box. But as Harper already noted, there is more going on in this box. It looks like at least 5 cables - and this light only needs 3 (1 incoming hot/neutral, 1 switched hot/neutral to the light, 1 hot/travelers to the other switch) so there is other stuff and that may matter quite a bit. In addition, the **make/model** of the smart switch matters a lot. Some use an ordinary 3-way (or even simple toggle) on the other end, some use a special "remote", some use an identical switch on each end.

Comment: And depending on how it is designed, the "usual" 3-way wiring (which has many variants, you have /3=hot+travelers, it should be easy to change to /3=switched hot+travelers, but there are others) will work fine, with others it has to be rearranged in a very specific way. Can't even begin to guess without more details.

Comment: @Harper If it was simply a matter of getting hot & neutral here for the smart switch, just change it from hot->black-of-/3->switch 2->travelers->switched hot to light **to** hot->switch 1->travelers->switch 2->switched-hot-on-black-of-/3->switched hot to light. But depending on how the smart switch wants to do its thing, switch 2 may or may not work properly.

Comment: @Ruskes care to explain why? If not, why even bother making the comment?

Comment: In the main downstairs switch box they have about 7 incoming Romex cables I've been able to identify where 4 of them are going.  From what I've read it appears that a 14/2 cable was tied into the power and ran directly to the chandelier then they ran a 14/2 cable back down to the switch box (far right side of picture) the black wire of this cable was ran to the 3 way switch and when the power is on there is no voltage to this black wire.  The black wire for the 14/3 cable was tied to the hot wires and white/red wires are connected to switch w/ black wire with no voltage described above.

Comment: I was trying to setup a Meross 3 way dimmer switch, which does say you can install with a load wire.  This diagram may be helpful. https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A1mMVtqHNuS.pdf